# ion-select using pipe transform, how to set default value?

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, pipe, ngfor, ion-select

I'm using pipe transform on `<ion-select-option *ngFor="let item of collection | myPipe:someValueToFilter" [value]="item">` and the pipe will do some filter, map and sort.

How can I set default value to `selectedItem` within `<ion-select [(ngModel)]="selectedItem">` in transformed collection after pipe transforming? (Let's say the first item in transformed collection)

Comment: Can you provide your code, please?

Comment: @MohammadBabaei I editted with some html code, about the pipe, it just does some normal filter, map and sort

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can use your pipe in `component.ts` file instead of the template like this:

```
@Component({
  ...
  providers: [MyPipe]
})
...
contractor(private myPipe: MyPipe)
```

then in your method or `ngOnInit` hook use your pipe to filter your data and use its value where you want, for example, set to the selected item.

```
 handleMyData(data): any {
  this.collection = this.myPipe.transform(data, filters)
  this.selectedItem = this.collection[0]
}
```

Comment: Sorry for late response, and thank you. I ended up using my service.ts which is similar to your answer. I found it still the easiest way to control data after all. Hands down to my lazy brain module